# problem in navigation in calendar application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have used this code:

[iPhone Development: Creating Native Calendar Like View](http://ved-dimensions.blogspot.com/2009/04/iphone-development-creating-native_09.html#comment-form)

to display calender in my project for ipad, and adjust the coordinate according to ipad, but as I navigating to next or previous month is coordinate get disturb. I am trying since last 2 days to searching from where its coordinate will adjust but its fruitless. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste the code that you have "changed", so that I can get some idea, what might be wrong.

Else I will need to download the project given on ved's website and use it in some demo project. I will need to do it in some free time. Before that can you try to use Calendar from [this](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) source.